# i.cluster command with GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, grass-6.4, image-classification

I am trying to do an unsupervised classification using GRASS GIS software. I have hyperspectral photo and now analyzing vegetation indices. Here is what I did:

1. Created 2000+ raster photos with different combinations of bands
2. Created raster of signatures for the same area using the same mask
3. Used `i.group` command to make group of all rasters that I have
4. Used `i.cluster` command - and here is my problem:

> WARNING: quantization file [gndvi_g40_n75] in mapset [xxx]
>   missing
>   WARNING: Unable to open header file for raster map 
>   WARNING: Unable to open raster map 
>   ERROR: Unable to open raster map

What should I do to not have those errors? It looks like `i.group` did not create everything properly...

So I cannot use `i.maxlik` without `i.cluster`

Comment: I removed some rasters and finally my group was taken by i.cluster. But now other problem: WARNING: Signature 1 is not valid (singular) - ignored WARNING: Signature 2 is not valid (singular) - ignored

Comment: Which operating system do you use? Because there is a related limit of how many files can be opened at the same time

Comment: I am using Linux by connecting with the server and working there, but normally I have Windows (I am not sure if this is important).

Comment: According to (random link) https://stackoverflow.com/a/870224/452464 Windows cannot open more than 512 at the same time. Maybe nowadays even 2000 but a GRASS GIS raster map consists of more than one file which needs to be opened. I suggest to open a bug report with details at https://trac.osgeo.org/grass#BugTracking in order to see if we could add a workaround here.